# Chrome background.js do not run unless manually click refresh icon in extension page every time the chrome first open

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Recently I am developing an extension which listens to tab change and do some stuff according to it. Now I wrote my main logic in chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener in background.js. I used unpacked version for development. However, to make the extension work, I need to manually go to the extension page and click refresh icon every time when first open a chrome window, otherwise, it will not work. Is there a way to make the background.js run the code without manually click refresh button? I tried onStartup but it doesn't work out.

Comment: A nonpersistent background script unloads after 5 seconds of inactivity so you need to register the listeners globally (they reregister every time the event page is loaded again), not inside onInstalled which is only for first-time initialization (often not necessary). See the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages).

Answer (score 0):

Although not ideal, you can make the background script run persistently if you modify your manifest.json to...

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },
  ...
}
```

This is not recommended because background scripts can use a lot of resources so you should use something like chromes messaging API to run only on set/specific events.

If you need to look into changing your background script, look at [*this*](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_migration) for more information.